# Redis command line SET value containing double quotes

Tags: redis

I want to use redis command line (using redis-cli) to store json values. This is what I do

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set test '{"a":"b"}'
```

This command fails with message :

```
Invalid argument(s)
```

I don't have problem with setting values that don't contain  double quotes. What is the correct way to escape double quotes?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add slashes to quotes

```
set test "{\"a\":\"b\"}"
```

Comment: When I do `get test` I get `"{\"a\":\"b\"}"`. Is the returned a string or json?

Answer (score 7):

We can use single quotes for storing the JSON value:

> set name '{"a":"b"}'

Run get query like: get name

> output : {"a":"b"}

Answer (score 6):

later redis has fixed this problem. single quote works fine.